# How to use moveit to plan multiple robot movements in parallel？

Tags: moveit, ros-galactic

There are two robots in my scene, and MoveGroupInterfaces were created for them respectively. I want to plan their movements in parallel, but the result is alternate execution. I implemented two robot planning services in the same ros node and created two threads to represent the clients of the two robots. They may call planning and execution at the same time, but the result is that the two robots execute alternately and cannot be completely parallel. What should I do?

ROS service node:

```
//moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface robot1_;
//moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface robot2_;
//moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_;

RobotCommander::RobotCommander()
        : Node("robot_commander"),
          node_(std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("example_group_node")),
        executor_(std::make_shared<rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor>()),
          robot1_(node_, "robot1"),
          robot2_(node_, "robot2"),
          planning_scene_() {
          executor_->add_node(node_);
          executor_thread_ = std::thread([this]() { this->executor_->spin(); });

 move_srv_ = create_service<robot_msgs::srv::MoveToPose>(
            "/robot/move_to_pose",
            std::bind(&RobotCommander::RobotMovetoTarget, this,
                    std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}

bool RobotCommander::RobotMovetoTarget(robot_msgs::srv::MoveToPose::Request::SharedPtr req,
                                       robot_msgs::srv::MoveToPose::Response::SharedPtr res) {
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan plan;        
    if (req->robot_name == "robot1") {
            robot1_.setPoseTarget(req->pose);
            bool success = static_cast<bool>(robot1_.plan(plan));
            return static_cast<bool>(robot1_.execute(plan));
        } else {
            robot2_.setPoseTarget(req->pose);
            bool success = static_cast<bool>(robot2_.plan(plan));
            return static_cast<bool>(robot2_.execute(plan));
        }
}
```

robot client node:

```
class Robot(Node):
    def __init__(self, node_name: str):
        super().__init__(node_name)
        sim_time = Parameter(
            "use_sim_time",
            rclpy.Parameter.Type.BOOL,
            True
        )
        self.name = self.get_name()
        self.set_parameters([sim_time])    
        self._move_cli = self.create_client(MoveToPose, "/robot/move_to_pose")

    def move_to(self, waypoints, avoid_collisions=True):
        request = MoveToPose.Request()
        request.waypoints = waypoints
        request.robot_name = self.name
        request.avoid_collisions = avoid_collisions
        future = self._move_cli.call_async(request)
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)
        if future.done():
            self.get_logger().info(f'move {self.name} to {waypoints}!')
            return True
        else:
            self.get_logger().warn(f'{self.name} can not move to {waypoints}......')
        return False
```

then create two thread:

```
executor = rclpy.executors.MultiThreadedExecutor()
robot1 = Robot('robot1')
robot2 = Robot('robot2')
executor.add(robot1)
executor.add(robot2)
threading.Thread(target= executor.spin(), args=()).start()
```

At this time, it is assumed that robot1 and robot2 continuously call move_to at the same time, but the result is that the two execute alternately.

Comment: I think it is best to show us some code (or provide a url to a github.com repository.) Please create a short code example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how you are attempting to run two instances of a service in parallel. Make the service job something very simple, like "sleep for 10 seconds".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have revised the question.

Answer (score 0):

There was a post about this with an answer *only yesterday*.

[How to perform simultaneous cooperative motion of multiple robots with moveit?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105584/how-to-perform-simultaneous-cooperative-motion-of-multiple-robots-with-moveit)

Comment: If this does not answer your question, please edit your post to explain how your situation differs from these previous questions.